# how to access MATLAB helper function?

Tags: matlab

I want to know how MATLAB does calculations in "hCSIRSMeasurements"function which is a MATLAB helper.

But I don't know how to access helper functions codes.

How can I access helper functions' code base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re looking for a sub-function, say `helper()` used in `main()`, then

```
which helper in main
```

will tell you where the function is defined. It could return the path to an M-file, which you can read, or to a P-file, which is encrypted, or to a MEX-file, which is compiled and cannot be read, or it could return the string “builtin”, which indicates the function is internal to MATLAB.